# jQuery animate table cell width percentage

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a table with 2 columns, when I animate the width to 66% it works fine, but when I animate it again (from 66% to 66%) it goes bigger and goes back to 66%.

The expected result is to keep at 66%, because it is already at 66%.

In the following example you can see how table change it size every time you click the table.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table').click(function(){
    $('.first').animate({'width':'66%'},400);
  });
});
```

```css
table{
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="first">click</td>
  <td class="secon">me</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Why does this happen?

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this solution -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table').click(function(){
    var tableWidth = $(this).width();
    $('.first').animate({'width': (tableWidth * 66 / 100) + 'px'}, 400);
  });
});
```

Demo URL - https://jsfiddle.net/im4aLL/xpvt214o/64222/

Comment: oh, not bad, it works for me, do you know why this happen?

Comment: @stramin percentage width is relative to parent width. When animate triggers it transforms width to x value to y value. I think, in your code - jQuery defined start value to {x}px but ends up to {x}% So i put calculated value to {x}px. Not sure about exact reason.

Answer (score 1):

Do a check on the current width and only animate when it's not 66%

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table').click(function(){
    if($('.first')[0].style.width != '66%'){
        $('.first').animate({'width':'66%'},400);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table{
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="first">click</td>
  <td class="secon">me</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it seems like it happen with 67% too, and maybe others numbers :(

Comment: The if statement must be the same as the width you're animating to